# Setting form validation rules in CodeIgniter without repeating code

Tags: php, codeigniter

How do I set validation rules in codeIgniter if the inputs have same validation rules like in this case its required.

```
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'Firstname', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('middlename', 'Middlename', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname', 'Lastname', 'required');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can simply make an array of fields and then iterator over the array

```
$fields = array('username' => 'Username', 'password' => 'Password', 'firstname' => 'Firstname');
foreach($fields AS $key=>$val){
 $this->form_validation->set_rules($key, $val, 'required')
}
```

next time, you just need to add new item(s) to the `$fields` array and it will auto add validation rules for you.